# Cancel HTTPWebRequest when server goes down

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows-services, httpwebrequest

I have created a Windows Service that calls a API (that returns JSON) with HTTPWebRequest.

The API doesn't return anything until it has something to "deliver". So I set the timeout quite high and lets the request wait until it receivs a response.

The problem is that when I test to turn off or disconnect the server running the API. The HTTPWebRequest doesn't stop the request. So I can't know if the API server has gone down.

The request code:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
Request.Method = "POST";
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Request.ContentLength = PostData.Length;
Request.Timeout = Timeout;
Request.KeepAlive = true;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(PostData);
}
using (HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        ResponseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to "break" the request when the requested server goes down?
I have tried using the webbrowser to call the API server and after a while disconnect it and that return an error to the webpage.

Comment: What do you mean with _"The HTTPWebRequest doesn't stop the request."_? An exception will be thrown if a timeout occurs or if a socket throws an exception. for those suggesting a background ping: that's a race condition. If a ping succeeds and the server goes down the second after, the following request will fail.

Comment: Well, I set the timeout to days, because thats how long a response could take. And I'm not getting another exception when the remote server disconnects which basically is my problem. It just seems to continue to wait for a response.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a background worker only cecking if the server is online. It has some disatvantages but may work fine.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. But would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to keep the requests asynchronous (See the BeginXXX methods in HttpWebRequest - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). 
Using the asynchronous APIs ensures that you are not blocked until you get a response from the server.

In addition to using the asynchronous APIs, you can have a heart-beat requests (that could be just a HEAD HTTP request to a ping service on the server, which returns an empty body and HTTP 200 status), to keep track that the server is alive. If this request times out, then server is not alive - in which case, you can cancel / just 'forget' that the request has been made.

Comment: I'm currently running the HTTPWebRequest in it's own thread, so it shouldn't block other things that nneds to run. But asynchronous calls might be better anyway? The ping/heart-beat might be the only way to check that the server is online.

Comment: Making a HTTP request in your own thread may not block the application, but the request as such is not asynchronous i.e., that thread is blocked effectively.
Using the asynchnronous APIs make sure that the request is submitted, and then executes the callback once there is a response, which lets u know that the request is complete. (But, in this particular case, where the server is down, it might never come).

Comment: @AndreasBergqvist, hope your problem is resolved. Did you try this solution, or something else?

Comment: Actually, no, it's not always good to make it asynchronous. OP is running his HttpWebRequest in its own thread so it is ALREADY asynchronous with respect to OP's main thread. Also, there are many times when people want synchronous web requests, especially when there is no other work that can be done until the web request returns data.